# Php implode empty array

Tags: php, implode

I have a simple array with no values assigned:

```
Array
(
    [field1] => 
    [field2] => 
)
```

then doing something like:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
   array_push($result, $val);
}

$data = implode("::", $result);
```

I end up with:

```
::
```

So how can I prevent implode generating separator if array values are empty?
If I have at least one value assigned:

```
Array
(
    [field1] => "hello"
    [field2] => 
)
```

Then implode does it's job fine.

Comment: Filter the array first for empty elements.

Comment: @Dagon Yes there is :P I just had one in my mind with `array_filter()`, but not combined with `implode()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) , for example in your case:

```
implode( ':', array_filter( $result ) );
```

That will filter your array before imploding it.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the array (Removing empty elements) before you actually implode your array.

According to the docs for `array_filter()`:

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

This means that (if you're dealing with only strings), '' or '0' will be removed. If 0 is a valid string in your `$result`, then use a custom callback function:

```
$result = array_filter($result, function($val) {
    return $val !== '';
});
```

**Final Code:**

```
$result = array(
    'field1' => '',
    'field2' => ''
);

$result = array_filter($result);

$data = implode("::", $result);
```

You can see it in action [here](https://3v4l.org/1KvYl).

EDIT: An alternative way, is to prevent empty values from getting into your array in the first place:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
   if ( $val !== '' ) {
       array_push($result, $val);
   }
}
```